# Why are instructions addresses on the top of the memory user space contrary to the linux process memory layout?

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void func() {}

int main() {
    printf("%p", &func);

    return 0;
}
```

This program outputted `0x55c4cda9464a`
Supposing that `func` will be stored in the `.text` section, and according to this figure, from `CS:APP`: [image]
I suppose that the address of `func` would be somewhere near the starting address of the `.text` section, but this address is somewhere in the middle. Why is this the case? Local variables stored on the stack have addresses near 2^48 - 1, but I tried to disassemble different C codes and the instructions were always located somewhere around that `0x55...` address.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I seem to be running the same system as the book but getting very different addresses for this section, also I thought that this was a standard because this particular layout is all over the books and articles

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Stop that. Suggesting people should not care about the addresses of their functions is saying people should expect to run only in an idealized C environment and never care about implementation details. That is bunk. Sometime after learning some programming basics, students take operating systems classes and learn about memory layouts. Somebody has to maintain operating systems. Somebody has to update program loaders. Somebody has to diagnose bugs involving them. Students need to learn these things and need to experiment with them. Do not stifle curiosity.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't write he _shouldn't_ care, I asked _why_ he cares? And I upvoted the question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I did not write you wrote he *shouldn’t* care, I wrote that *sugggesting* people should not care is bad. There is a clear implication in asking the question that one ought to have a reason for wanting to acquire knowledge. It is a bad and harmful attitude. Stop it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't suggest anything, I just asked for some more information on an otherwise good question. I'm sorry if you misinterpreted this. I suggest we delete our comments which don't really add something useful to the question.

Comment: @TortelliniTeusday I suppose you don't have the exact same system (which one BTW?) as the one they used in the book. If you try on [GDB Online](https://onlinegdb.com/r1EOP7YGP) the output is closer to what you expect. OTOH on [Ideone](https://www.ideone.com/dPYEQ3) the output is closer to what you get on your system.

Comment: @Jabberwocky as I said, I thought that this was the case for all _linux x86-64 using gcc_, but as it turns out not to be that global, then yes I'm _not_ running the same system they used, of course!

Comment: @TortelliniTeusday also have a look at [this](https://onlinegdb.com/BkjoYQKzw), you can see that depending on the size, `malloc` allocates memory from quite different places.

Comment: @TortelliniTeusday also try to compile your code with the `-m32` switch which will generate a 32 bit binary whose output will again be quite different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcc`, when configured with `--enable-default-pie`<sup>1</sup> (which is the default), produces [Position Independent Executables(PIE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables). Which means the load address isn't same as what linker specified at compile-time (0x400000 for x86_64). This is a security mechanism so that [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Linux) (ASLR) <sup>2</sup> can be enabled. That is, gcc compiles with [`-pie`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) option by default.

If you compile with `-no-pie` option (`gcc -no-pie file.c`), then you can see the address of `func` is closer to 0x400000.

On my system, I get:

```
$ gcc -no-pie t.c
$ ./a.out 
0x401132
```

You can also check the load address with [`readelf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html):

```
$ readelf -Wl a.out | grep LOAD
 LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x000478 0x000478 R   0x1000
 LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000 0x0001f5 0x0001f5 R E 0x1000
 LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000402000 0x0000000000402000 0x000158 0x000158 R   0x1000
 LOAD           0x002e10 0x0000000000403e10 0x0000000000403e10 0x000228 0x000230 RW  0x1000
```

---

<sup>1</sup> you can check this with `gcc --verbose`.

<sup>2</sup> You may also notice that address printed by your program is different in each run. That's because of ASLR. You can disable it with:

```
$ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

ASLR is enabled on Linux by default.

Comment: Interesting...but if that were the case, then why wouldn't the `0x55...` address be randomized?

Comment: @jackw11111 I have not fully read the answer, yet. I forgot to mention that randomization occurs but it's still around that address. I think that it only randomizes the start of the segment in the range of couple of megabytes if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: @TortelliniTeusday I can reproduce this behaviour on my system too. Repeats around `0x55`, sometimes `0x56`.

Comment: @jackw11111 On x86, [ELF_ET_DYN_BASE](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/arch/x86/include/asm/elf.h#L251) is calculated to be around that value (if I compile with ASLR disabled the starting address on x86_64 I see is `0x555555555145`). I believe ASLR calc is applied on top of this but limited to certain number of bits.